# Javascript: Assign value from the child page to parent page

Tags: javascript

I have created a pop-up window using the following script.

> var CarricularWindow =
>   window.open("AddCarriculars.aspx",
>   "Extra Carriculars", "height=200,
>   width=200");

This pop-up window contains a TextBox and a button. Now, when the user enters some data on that textbox and clicks on the button. I want the data to be copied to a TextBox which is there on the calling page.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a javascript function in the calling window:

```
function setText(text) {
    document.getElementById('yourtextboxid').value = text;
}
```

and in the popup window when the user clicks on the button:

```
var text = document.getElementById('someothertextboxid').value;
window.opener.setText(text);
```